# Debugger for Chrome: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: visual-studio-code

Windows 10 x64 Professional
Visual Studio Code v1.26.1
Debugger for Chrome 4.9.0

I have the simple config (`launch.json`):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `launch.json` file is located in the `.vscode` subdirectory of my project folder. Also my folder contains the `index.html` file.

I open my project folder in Visual Studio Code and press `F5` key, but I get the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error in the new Google Chrome instance. I.e. the browser can't to open my `index.html` page.

But this variant works fine:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against index.html",
            "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html"
        }
    ]
}
```

Why I have the problem with the `localhost` variant and how can I solve it?

Comment: Are you serving the file on port 8080?  Some things, like browserSync default to port 3000 and you must change it to 8080.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem this week. As far as I understand the first launch config (using URL and webroot) needs a local (f.i. node.js) web server up and running.

The second launch config "just" runs the local file(s).